# Google Sheets move a row to another sheet on 2 cell criteria in current row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to move a row from one sheet based on 2 cell criteria:

1. box is checked (TRUE)
2. Cell text = CLOSED but this cell actually has a vlookup to another sheet `(=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A42,'01 - Master RO Entry Sheet'!A:L,3, ""),""))`

Here is what I have:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named "03 - Schedule"
  // target sheet of move to named "History"
  // getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to colu 2 or B
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "03 - Schedule" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == true && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == "CLOSED"){
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("10 - Master History");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the current behavior? What do you want to change?

Answer (score 0):

here is an update of the code according to your correction of the question

```
const archScheme = [{sourceSheet: '01 - Master RO Entry Sheet', targetSheet: '11 - Customer History', srcColumn: 'A'},
                    {sourceSheet: '02 - Estimates to Complete', targetSheet: '12 - Estimate History', srcColumn: 'A'}];

// the function moves row #rowNum from 'fromSheet' to 'toSheet'
function moveDataRow(rowNum,fromSheet,toSheet,ss){
  if (rowNum==-1) return;
  let scrSheet = ss.getSheetByName(fromSheet),
      trgSheet = ss.getSheetByName(toSheet);

  scrSheet.getRange(rowNum+':'+rowNum).moveTo(
    trgSheet.getRange(trgSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()+1,1));
  scrSheet.deleteRow(rowNum);

  // here we replace the names of the sheets in the formulas according to archScheme
  let range = trgSheet.getRange(trgSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()+':'+trgSheet.getDataRange().getNumRows()),
      originalFormulas = range.getFormulas()[0],
      originalValues = range.getValues()[0];
  range.setValues([originalFormulas.map((cell,i) => { if (cell=='') { return originalValues[i] } 
                                                        else 
                                                      { archScheme.forEach(sh => cell = cell.replace(sh.sourceSheet,sh.targetSheet))
                                                        return cell}  } )])    
}

function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range, 
      row = range.rowStart,
      col = range.columnStart,
      scrSheet = range.getSheet();
  
  if (scrSheet.getName()=='03 - Schedule' && col==2 && range.getValue()==true && range.offset(0,1).getValue()=='CLOSED'){
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
        orderNum = range.offset(0,1-col).getValue();
    moveDataRow(row,'03 - Schedule','10 - Master History',ss);
    archScheme.forEach(sheets => {
      moveDataRow(
        [].concat(...ss.getSheetByName(sheets.sourceSheet).getRange(sheets.srcColumn+':'+sheets.srcColumn).getValues()).indexOf(orderNum) + 1,
        sheets.sourceSheet,
        sheets.targetSheet,
        ss)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: That works GREAT. but how do i get my conditional formatting to move along with it?

Comment: one more question. FORGIVE ME, i am an old Borland Delphi Programmer and all this is NEW to me.....
i have 2 more sheets that everything is keyed of a Work Order #. how would i go about this same code you helped with looking for Column A current Row and using the Work Order number as the index in the other sheets and MOVEING or DELETEING them in other sheets once a job is complete and meets the criteria in this current code you provided? Once i see code that works, i analyze it and see how it works and that is how i learn to code. i am a VERY VISUAL person.

Comment: Hi, @Rick Crowell. I don't quite understand your question about conditional formatting. If you have some conditional formatting on your '03 - Schedule' sheet, then this conditional formatting rule will not be moved to the target sheet when you move the rows. You can set a similar conditional formatting rule on the '10 - Master History' sheet as well.

Comment: As for your second question, the algorithm is as follows: When transferring a row from `'03 - Schedule'` to `'10 - Master History'` you need to detect `Work Order #`. Then read the column with Work Orders from your sheet from which you want to remove/move the row with that Work Order. Then run through the array and find the row number to move. You can then use the found row number to move/remove that row from the worksheet. _If you make an example of your table with several rows of data - then I can help you to build code_

Comment: here is a copy of the sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2tfpI2OR1Ky0Dy8uf2ck3RwXz231-MGCGJ49n3Oduo/edit?usp=sharing if this helps.

01 - Master RO Entry Sheet would be one sheet searched then move the found row to a (11 - Customer History) sheet and then move the found row from (02 - Estimates to Complete) to (13 - Estimate History)

Comment: A copy of your spreadsheet certainly helped. I updated the code - now the first thing is the `Work Order #`, then the line from the sheet `'03 - Schedule'` to the sheet `'10 - Master History'` is moved. After that, the line numbers for `Work Order #` on sheets `'01 - Master RO Entry Sheet'` and `'02 - Estimates to Complete'` are determined and the lines found, if any, are transferred to sheets `'11 - Customer History'` and `'13 - Estimate History'`. The simple transfer of the data lines broke the links to the master sheet in the formulas - so I added a block to update the links in the code

Comment: Sergy, thank you. i will look at that today. SEEING this stuff helps me figure out how to do it on my own. kinda like riding a bike. i have to see stuff to be able to do it.